# Resetting and Stopping a function

Tags: java, andengine

I have a function that orders a movement to a sprite, how am I gonna reset it? whereas it will do the same order all over again, and after another condition is triggered it will stop

inside my function there is a boolean and a float.

```
MyFunction(float a, float b, boolean trig){

if(true){
    //your condition/order
        }
    else
        {
            //do nothing
        }

}
```

here is my code for resetting:

```
MyFunction(false or true).reset();
```

here is my code for stopping:

```
MyFunction(false);
```

is there something wrong in my code? or are there any better style of doing this, thanks in advance :)

Comment: btw in "MyFunction(false or true).reset();" it will error if I don't put any boolean in it so I put false or true

Comment: why the heck did you vote down on it? I did not exerted any effort? I was just asking If how am I able to stop a function? it's not like asking on how to do it, I was hoping that someone would answer like this "MyFUnction().stop" zzzzzz

Answer (score 1):

you wrote if(true), instead if(trig)

Comment: how about resetting it?